# Where does $i^2$ lie on the imaginary axis?

Tags: complex-numbers

I have always had this question in mind. I am aware that a complex number is of the form a+ib can be represented in a complex plane where the real part "a" is represented on the x-axis or the real axis and "b" is represented on the y-axis, the imaginary axis (I do not understand the concept of complex number very deeply; which is why its a matter of interest for me; so please correct me if this understanding of mine is wrong in any way), but what if a=0 and b=i? where would such a number be plotted on the complex plane?

Comment: Essentially by definition, $i^2 = -1$.

Comment: $a+bi$ commonly uses real $a$ and $b$. If you allow complex (not just purely imaginary) $a$ and $b$, then the complex number $a+bi$ can be represented in multiple ways.

Comment: @peterwhy thank you for your comment. could you please give an example of one such way (of the multiple) so i can understand? :)

Comment: @CoverSpot, an example is the complex number $i$.  You could have $a = 0, b = 1$ or $a = i, b=0$.  In other words, $0 + i = i + 0i = i$

Comment: @CoverSpot Or for any complex number $a+bi$, you can also represent it as $(a+bi)+0i = 0+(-ai+b)i$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$a+bi$ has coordinates $x = a, y = b$ when $a$ and $b$ are *real*.  When they are not real, you will have to do multiplication of complex numbers to write the thing in standard form.

So $i^2 = -1 = -1 + 0i$ which has coordinates $(-1,0)$.  It does not lie on the imaginary axis at all.